# Couldn't get datomic client artifact

Tags: clojure, datomic

I'm following the [on-prem "getting started" guide](https://docs.datomic.com/on-prem/getting-started/connect-to-a-database.html) to, well, "get started" on datomic, with the end goal of migrating a side project app to ions later.

When starting my repl I get `Could not find artifact com.datomic:client-pro:jar:0.9.5786 in central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)`.

Here's my `~/.m2/settings.xml` file:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>my.datomic.com</id>
      <username>my-email</username>
      <password>my-key</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

And my `deps.edn` file:

```
{:deps
 {some-other-libs {:mvn/version "blah"}
  com.datomic/client-pro {:mvn/version "0.9.5786"}
  }
 :mvn/repos
 {"my.datomic.com" {:url "https://my.datomic.com/repo"}
  }
 }
```

For some reason I can't see what I did wrong, "it" doesn't seem to try fetching the dependency from "my.datomic.com" but rather gets stuck after not finding it on maven central.

I'm using Clojure 1.9.0. Can anyone help?

Comment: If I try to make the server named "central" point to "my.datomic.com/repo" I get Could not find artifact com.datomic:client-pro:jar:0.9.5786 in central (https://my.datomic.com/repo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mixed-up the dependency versions between the getting-started and the dependency example specified in the my.datomic.com/account page.

The correct version should be 0.8.28:

```
{:deps
 {
  com.datomic/client-pro {:mvn/version "0.8.28"}
  }
 :mvn/repos
 {"my.datomic.com" {:url "https://my.datomic.com/repo"}
  }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

I have not yet tried the *on-prem* version of Datomic, but if you just want to get started you can clone the following repo:

https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo-datomic

which includes a (curated) copy of `datomic-free`

Comment: The project you are referring to uses leiningen. I have no problem retrieving the datomic-pro dependency using leiningen, it is tools.deps that causes this it seems.